# jQuery create object with selected attribute and value

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have different select option for country, city, zip.
Now my requirement is to when someone changes the values from dropdown it should create an array object with selected values. So to achieve this I have done something like this

```
var SearchParams = [];

jQuery('.form-type-select').each(function() {
    let Attribute = jQuery(this).attr('data-attribute-name');
    
    $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i, e){
    obj = {};
        var self = jQuery(this).val();
        if( Attribute == 'country' ) {
            obj[Attribute] = self;
        }

        if( Attribute == 'city' ) {
            obj[Attribute] = self;
        }
        SearchParams.push(obj);
    });
});

console.log(SearchParams);
```

It is showing output like this

```
[
    {country: 'France'}
    {country: 'UK'}
    {country: 'Spain'}
    {city : 'Toulouse'}
    {city : 'Lyon'}
    {city : 'Yorkshire'}
]
```

But I want the output should look like this

```
[
    {country: 'France', 'UK', 'Spain'}
    {city : 'Toulouse', 'Lyon', 'Yorkshire'}
]
```

So can someone tell me how to achieve this? Any help and suggestions would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new *JSON Object* on each iteration i.e : `obj = {};` .Instead you can simply create key `SearchParams["country"]` and then push value inside this key .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var SearchParams = {}; //create obj
SearchParams["country"] = new Array() //create keys..
SearchParams["city"] = new Array()
jQuery('.form-type-select').each(function() {
  let Attribute = jQuery(this).attr('data-attribute-name');
  $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i, e) {
    var self = jQuery(this).val();
    if (Attribute == 'country') {
      SearchParams["country"].push(self); //push inside key...
    }
    if (Attribute == 'city') {
      SearchParams["city"].push(self);
    }
  });
});

console.log(SearchParams);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-type-select" data-attribute-name="country"><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked></div>
<div class="form-type-select" data-attribute-name="city"><input type="checkbox" value="2" checked></div>
<div class="form-type-select" data-attribute-name="country"><input type="checkbox" value="7" checked></div>
<div class="form-type-select" data-attribute-name="city"><input type="checkbox" value="45" checked></div>
```